# How to remove F-Secure with parental lock - forgotten password

Tags: uninstall

I'm trying to get rid of F-Secure Internet Security 2011 but I am unable to run the unistaller as the parental lock is active and I don't know the password. It would be possible to reset the password with the serial key but the program was pre-installed on the machine and no serial is known.. Any ideas on how to remove the program completely without messing up the whole system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to their FTP site, and download, and run their "uninstalltiontool.exe".

ftp://ftp.f-secure.com/support/tools/uitool

It it does not work, boot into safe mode, and stop any F-Secure services that may be running, and kill any related processes, and then run it again.

Comment: Or try a clean boot.